# C# WPF. Disable textbox1 if textbox2 has text and vise versa. Enable if both are empty

Tags: c#, wpf

C# WPF. Hi, I have Two textboxes textbox1 and textbox2, both enabled at initial stage. When you enter text in one of the textboxes the other should disable. and vise versa. When you delete the text in the textbox, both textboxes should be enabled. I am very new at c# WPF need step by step instructions in detail. Would like simplest code if possible. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a code writing service. You must provide code that you've tried and specific errors that you've encountered. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you asking where the code should go? If so, check the `TextChanged` event of the textboxes. If that's not it, then which part are you stuck on? Please show what you have so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this, where inside the text changed event of each textbox, you set the `IsEnabled` property of the other textbox based on the length of text in the current one (if the length of the text is zero, enable the other box, otherwise disable it):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2 != null) textBox2.IsEnabled = textBox1.Text.Length == 0;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1 != null) textBox1.IsEnabled = textBox2.Text.Length == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rufus, this is exactly what is looking for.